# Changed font colours in ReSharper test runner?

Tags: colors, resharper

I know you change fonts/colours within ReSharper by selecting *tools > options > Fonts and Colors* however I can't find the specific option to change the colour of text within ReSharpers test runner (specifically the red when tests fail).
(Either that or changing the selection highlight)

[image: The red/blue contrast isn't appealing]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the ReSharper text colour under Visual Studio->Options...->Environment->Fonts and Colors ?

Comment: The issue is I don't know which option to change, that menu is cumbersome and could really do with some QoL improvements.